# Assertion failed when use opencv in python

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, distortion

I am doing Camera Calibration in opencv in python and I followed the tutorials on [this page](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html?highlight=initundistortrectifymap). My code is completely copied from the page with tiny adjustment on the parameters.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob

# termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((6*7,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:7,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)

# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.

images = glob.glob('../easyimgs/*.jpg')
print('...loading')
for fname in images:
    print(f'processing img:{fname}')
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    print('grayed')
    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (8, 11),None)

    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    if ret == True:
        print('chessboard detected')
        objpoints.append(objp)

        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners2)

        # Draw and display the corners
        img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (8,11), corners2,ret)
        cv2.namedWindow('img',0)
        cv2.resizeWindow('img', 500, 500)
        cv2.imshow('img',img)
        cv2.waitKey(500)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()


img2 = cv2.imread("../easyimgs/5.jpg")
print(f"type objpoints:{objpoints[0].shape}")
print(f"type imgpoints:{imgpoints[0].shape}")

ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)
h,  w = img2.shape[:2]
newcameramtx, roi=cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx,dist,(w,h),1,(w,h))
dst = cv2.undistort(img2, mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx)

# crop the image
x,y,w,h = roi
dst = dst[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.namedWindow('result', 0)
cv2.resizeWindow('result', 400, 400)
cv2.imshow('result',dst)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but when I run it, an error shows up as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*/undistortion.py", line 51, in <module>
    ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\calib3d\src\calibration.cpp:3143: error: (-215:Assertion failed) ni == ni1 in function 'cv::collectCalibrationData'
```

*[Here is my image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXSdO.jpg)*

---

I have searched on the Internet that many people are also confronted with this problem. But most of the solution on blog is saying that this is caused by the type of the first and second parameters of `calibrateCamera()` which is `objpoints` and  `imgpoints`. But those are all solution for opencv on c++.

Could any one tell me how to solve it in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of entries in objpoints and imgpoints must be the same. This assertion means they aren't. It looks like you're creating a set of 6*7=42 objpoints, which is intended for a chessboard of 6x7 intersections, but your actual chessboard has 8*11=88 intersections. So as you process images, your objpoints and imgpoints lists get different lengths.  You need to modify your creation/initialization of objp to have 8*11=88 points, whose coordinates correspond to the real physical coordinates on your chessboard.

To do this, you'll need to really understand the code you are using. Putting in more debug statements will help you to trace through what is happening in your code.

And note that the Python API to OpenCV is just a wrapper around the C++ API, so any solution for using OpenCV with C++ are (usually) relevant in Python too.